# Is it possible to copy a complete instance and change Keypair Name and Instance Type

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

We set up a free trial EC2 instance some time ago, and it's now time to beef it up.  I tried this awhile back on a different instance and wound up deleting the whole thing, and have stayed away from doing it ever since.

In short, I'd like to :

1. Keep the EC2 instance (including the OS and all installed software, etc.)
2. Specify a larger size beyond the t2.micro that we initially chose.
3. Add more disk space
4. Change the Key-Pair Name of the instance

The important thing is the Keypair Name, so that seems to imply a new instance alltogether, but I don't know which of the above can be done with which processes.

I hope this is possible without creating a brand new instance and installing the whole server/software again. If someone could be so kind as to list the steps and "things" (instances, images, AMI's ???) that should be done to accomplish this, it would be very much appreciated. :)

Comment: All of these things are trivial tasks, but #4 sounds a bit like an [XY](http://xyproblem.info).  What is the motivation for changing the key pair name?  What are you *really* trying to accomplish at that step?

Comment: The powers that be insist....conventions, I think.

Comment: For the record, it sounds like someone who doesn't understand what they are asking you to do is wasting your time.  If you want to change the authorized key on an instance, you just change it... on the instance itself.  What the console shows is of no significance... **the console shows the key that was initially authorized at launch**, and nothing more.   That's why you can't change it, there, later -- because, later, it's only a historical artifact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

- add the new key manually to the new instance
- create a new instance using "launch more like this" context menu item
- create snapshot of the existing drive
- restore the snapshot to a new volume with the size you like
- delete default volume of the new instance and attach the volume from the previous step

[image]

Without the first step your new key won't be saved when you replace the volume, without last three steps you won't have your data on the new instance.

p.s.: if you're good you'll see incorrect key pair name in console and you don't really need TWO instances at the same time then you can add the second key manually then stop and resize the instance.